# Navigation command works when called by button but not when called programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I have a WPF app which has two User Controls. On one user control, I have a list of buttons which are all binded to a command that changes the ViewModel from that user control to the other, with a command parameter of the button's content. This works just fine. If I click any of the buttons, the command successfully runs and the ViewModel changes to the other user control with the button's content being passed through. However, if I try and execute the command in the ViewModel's constructor (after the command has been instantiated), it does not work. When I set a breakpoint and follow it, it appears to change the ViewModel, but the view does not appear to change in the window. I cannot figure out what the difference is between executing the command programmatically compared to with a button.

I am new to MVVM, so please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly or if you need more info.

ViewModel 1 (where I create the buttons and try to execute command programmatically):

```
public class SelectProgramViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public List<string> ProgramNames { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Button> ProgramButtons { get; set; }
        public SettingsObject SettingsObject { get; set; }
        public PersonalSettings PersonalSettings { get; set; }

        public ICommand SelectProgramCommand { get; }

        public SelectProgramViewModel(MappingStore mappingStore, NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            NavigationService<ParsingViewModel> navigationService = new NavigationService<ParsingViewModel>(
                navigationStore,
                () => new ParsingViewModel(mappingStore, navigationStore));

            SelectProgramCommand = new SelectProgramCommand(this, mappingStore, navigationService);

            // Retrieve settings information
            const string settingsObjectPath = "I:\\Next Phase\\Logistics\\Applications\\WM Parser\\Resources\\SettingsObject.json";
            SettingsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsObject>(File.ReadAllText(settingsObjectPath));
            PersonalSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonalSettings>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "WM Parser", "PersonalSettings.json")));

            // Create program buttons
            ProgramNames = SettingsObject.ProgramMappings.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            ProgramButtons = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
            foreach (var programName in ProgramNames)
            {
                ProgramButtons.Add(
                    new Button()
                    {
                        Content = programName,
                        Command = SelectProgramCommand,
                        CommandParameter = programName,

                        Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5)
                    });
            }

            // Check if last used program exists
            if (PersonalSettings.LastUsedProgramName != null &&
                SettingsObject.ProgramMappings.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(PersonalSettings.LastUsedProgramName))
            {
                SelectProgramCommand.Execute(PersonalSettings.LastUsedProgramName);
            }
        }
    }
```

SelectProgramCommand:

```
public class SelectProgramCommand : CommandBase
    {
        private readonly SelectProgramViewModel _viewModel;
        private readonly MappingStore _programStore;
        private readonly NavigationService<ParsingViewModel> _navigationService;

        public SelectProgramCommand(SelectProgramViewModel viewModel, MappingStore programStore, NavigationService<ParsingViewModel> navigationService)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
            _programStore = programStore;
            _navigationService = navigationService;
        }

        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _programStore.NovaMapping = _viewModel.SettingsObject.NovaMapping;
            _programStore.ParsingMapping = _viewModel.SettingsObject.ParsingMapping;
            _programStore.SelectedProgram = _viewModel.SettingsObject.ProgramMappings.First(x => x.Name == parameter.ToString());

            _navigationService.Navigate();
        }
    }
```

CommandBase (which SelectProgramCommand inherits):

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

        public abstract void Execute(object parameter);

        protected void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

NavigationService:

```
public class NavigationService<TViewModel>
        where TViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;
        private readonly Func<TViewModel> _createViewModel;

        public NavigationService(NavigationStore navigationStore, Func<TViewModel> createViewModel)
        {
            _navigationStore = navigationStore;
            _createViewModel = createViewModel;
        }

        public void Navigate()
        {
            _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = _createViewModel();
        }
    }
```

NavigationStore:

```
public class NavigationStore
    {
        public event Action CurrentViewModelChanged;

        private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get => _currentViewModel;
            set
            {
                _currentViewModel = value;
                OnCurrentViewModelChanged();
            }
        }

        private void OnCurrentViewModelChanged()
        {
            CurrentViewModelChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no difference except the timing. You have not posted enough code to review the complete initialization procedure in order to make statements about particular timing issues. Some notes: why are you creating controls (buttons) in your view model? This violates MVVM. You must use DataTemplate for this purpose. WPF will autogenerate the controls (buttons) for you [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Secondly, you should follow the common C# event pattern and always provide a sender and an event argument. You can use `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<T>` as event type [How to publish events that conform to .NET Guidelines (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines).

Comment: Lastly, you should not execute potentially long running operations in your constructor. For example, there are async APIs you can use improve the performance when reading or derserializing files. But there is no async context for constructors. For performance reasons you should consider to use the integrated .NET JSON API instead of the 3rd party library you are currently using [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0).

Comment: There is more to improve, but those are the most critical points, especially the first is very crucial. Please update your question to provide a minimal viable example that reproduces the issue so that we can review proper code with complete context.